# iPhone/iPad - Problem in generating .p12 and .pem files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, certificate

In one of my project, I have to implement Apple Push Notification service. For this, I have followed all the steps given in [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1). I had successfully created the Certificate, added it to my provisioning profile and applied that profile to my application also.
All are fine.
However, when I am trying to generate the .p12 file from my certificate, I am getting 2 windows; first is asked for password to generate the file (I had set it also) and second is asked a permission to read my Key present in my Certificate (This is the problem). Since I haven't set any password for generating this certificate (in fact, I hadn't being asked to choose any password to generate this file), how could I provide this. Please help me, as without creating this file I can not proceed further (because the creation of .pem file is depend on this file).
Any hint or suggestion would be a great help to me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are prompted for the second time for the password to read the certificate from keychain access, it means u need to provide the credentials for keychain access and not for the certificate you want to export.

Comment: Thats right and first time it prompts for the passphrase to export the file. +1.

Comment: I tried to enter my domain password too (by using which I am currently working on the machine), however it is not working.

Comment: I restarted the computer and tried. It worked for the keychain password. Sorry for the delay response. +1

Answer (score 1):

First time it asks for the password, it is used to set the passphrase and you can also type nothing and it will still work. Next time since its protected by keychain access, it would want a valid user accessing the data. The password it asks is your admin user's password so that it can export that certificate to a valid user only.

Comment: Now, after providing the password for certificate, it is prompting an error saying "You failed to provide the necessary administrator authorization"